# Artifact Version Search API Call in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to integrate below's REST API call into Groovy and use [Jenkin's Dynamic Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) to list all the versions of the artifact. Please could you assist with the groovy script

The Artifactory version search [REST API method](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch) can be used to get a list of all available artifact versions by GroupId and ArtifactId in local, remote or virtual repositories.
For example:

```
GET /api/search/versions?g=org.acme&a=artifact&repos=libs-release-local
{
"results": [
    {
    "version": "1.2",
    "integration": false
    },{
        "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "integration": true
    },{
        "version": "1.0",
    "integration": false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a [small example](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/blob/b60b66e840139d730bd58feb69406e2cf10ed029/templates/jenkins-jobs/seed-chef/seed_jobdsl.groovy.erb#L6-L7) for you, but you should also try it yourself.